# SHA3 Keccak, absorbing data to the state

Tags: hash, sha-3, keccak

I'm working on implementation of keccak algorithm and have one problem. Tell me please, takeing an example "test": will state (before block permutations, but after padding - pad10*1) look like this:

{80...0 0 0 0 0} {0 0 0 174736574 0} {0 0 0 0 0} {0 0 0 0 0} {0 0 0 0 0}

or maybe like this:

{80...0 0 0 0 0} {0 0 0 0 0} {0 0 0 0 0} {0 174736574 0 0 0} {0 0 0 0 0}

assuming that padded "test" look like this:
0x0000000174736574,
0x0000000000000000,
0x0000000000000000,
0x0000000000000000,
0x0000000000000000,
0x0000000000000000,
0x0000000000000000,
0x0000000000000000,
0x8000000000000000,

I mean: 174736574 will be on A[1,3] or A[3,1] or somwhere elese?

It's hard for me to understand, because i implemented all functions. I checked all functions - they work properly. But my hash is still different that proper hash calculated on the websites. I suppose that mistake is in absorbing phase. I will be gratefull for answer. 
And if i am wrong, how properly put data into the state?

Comment: I don't know which one of the persons at NIST decided to explicitly require Little Endian (maybe Intel had something to do with that) but it is annoying me like hell. They should have used network byte order.

Comment: https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/12720/keccak-padding-implementation-and-bit-ordering?rq=1